# When does it become better to have miners output directly into wagons rather than loading the wagons from chests using inserters?

Tags: factorio

Thinking about my prior question about train speed, I realized that how fast trains can be loaded and unloaded would also matter. The wiki clearly states when a single miner can fill a belt, but it says nothing about this. At mining productivity 350, triple speed 3 modules can let a miner fill a blue belt. At 890, the modules are no longer needed. However, how many does it take where just having them output directly into a cargo wagon is better than using inserters?

The problem is the game, as usual, doesn't give you enough numbers. We don't actually know the throughput of inserters. I know from experience that 6 stack inserters seems to be able to fill 2 blue belts (or three if you use blue undergrounds so you can have 12 inserters on each wagon). I don't know about the math though. Based on that, does that mean that 4 miners would have to get to where they can fill 2 or 3 blue belts? Since miners with speed 3s can fill a belt on their own and there's four, wouldn't that mean that mining productivity would needn't need to go all the way up to 350 to fill a wagon faster than inserters can? Where is the cutoff point where that would be the more practical option (beyond making it easier to have multiple trains visit one mine)?

Comment: The game does actually give you the numbers. It just doesn't hand them to you on a platter. Plenty of ways to build belt monitors and get per-minute belt content data. Of course, inserter throughput rate varies depending on how it picks stuff up from the belt. fwiw a single wagon with 12 stack inserters going in gets about 27,72 inputs per second. Multiply by stack size and you have your point of reference.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, a wagon can be connected to 4 drills or 12 inserters at the same time (with some room for burner inserters which results in an awkward layout, so they won't be included in this answer)

[image]

Further, according to the wiki, a stack inserter has a speed of approximately 2.31 turns per second. Multiply this by 12 and you get 27.72 insertion operations per second assuming maximum inserter contact area. Multiply that by the max stack size of an insterter (also 12) and you get a throughput benchmark of 332.64 items per second.

In other words, a single drill must be able to output a quarter of that, i.e. 83.16 items per second in order to compete, not accounting for inserters being able to be hooked up to chests.

Comment: Note that 27.69/s is the rate for moving from chest to chest; moving from belt to chest [depends critically on many factors including orientation](https://wiki.factorio.com/Inserters#Belt_to_chest_(perpendicular)) but is typically in the range of 15/s.